# On Special Deviations of a Score Sequence

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Can anyone help me to my problem?

First of all, I will introduce the definition of **deviation sequence**, and **special deviations**.

> 1. Let $<S_1,...,S_n>$ be any sequence of integers. The **deviation sequence of $<S_1>$** is the sequence $<d_i>$ where $d_i=S_i-i+1$.
> 2. Let $<S_i>$ be any sequence of integers with deviation sequence $<d_i>$. A term of the sequence $d_u$ is a **special deviation** if either $d_i=0$ for all $i>u$ or there exists $v>u$ such that $d_v>0$ and $d_k=0$ for all $u<i<v$.

We had our lecture about special deviations of a score sequence $<S_1,S_2,...,S_n>$ of a tournament $T$. Note that a **score sequence** of a tournament $T$ is the non-decreasing sequence of **outdegrees** of every point in $T$.

We stopped upon a particular result, which is the following:

> *A non-decreasing sequence $n$ of integers $<S_i>$ is a score sequence if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{k}d_i≥0$ for all special deviations $d_k$, with equality for the rightmost (or last) special deviation.*

We have proven the necessity in our class but left the sufficiency as an assignment. My plan of action is that, in order to show that $<S_i>$ is a score sequence, I have to use the following result:

> *A non-decreasing sequence of integers $<S_i>$ is a score sequence if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{k}d_i≥0$ for all $k=1,...,n$, with equality for $k=n$.*

Is my plan of action enough? If so, how will I inject it to the proof?

We conclude our lecture with another problem, which is left as an addition to the assignment.

> *Let $<d_i>$ be the deviation sequence of the non-decreasing sequence of integers $<S_i>$. Then $<d_i>$ has at most $(n+1)/3$ special deviations.*

I am a bit confused if this problem requires PMI or just a simple combinatorial proof. But I am much convinced that a simple combinatorial proof will do. Is my action right?

I gladly appreciate all your answers and comments regarding my problem. Thank you and more power!